# How to create "100% stacked" bar charts in plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I am trying to generate a stacked bar chart with plotly, specifically one that is "100%-stacked," like this:-

https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/13-percent-stacked-barplot

I am using the following code:-

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
binnum_attr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
tnl_attr=[164549.654, 278570.473, 201857.2155, 146326.9935, 116167.091, 98121.201, 384025.989, 786854.992, 502627.797, 306844.9995, 452795.6745, 271533.2325, 143591.5138]
pop_attr=[296699, 195322, 82853, 42382, 26001, 17926, 47187, 46586, 15508, 6500, 6412, 2339, 785]
verbose_customdata = np.stack((binnum_attr, tnl_attr, pop_attr), axis=-1)

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['3.618', '1.526', '0.899', '0.674', '0.587', '0.566', '0.632', '0.411', '0.139', '0.081', '0.046', '0.024', '0.060'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M0", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M0 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M0', marker_color='rgb(128,128,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['36.797', '21.312', '12.348', '9.136', '8.275', '8.028', '9.105', '5.944', '2.473', '1.225', '0.725', '0.394', '0.377'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M1", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M1 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M1', marker_color='rgb(230,25,75)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['45.265', '40.620', '30.699', '23.548', '20.190', '18.252', '18.068', '13.085', '6.579', '3.656', '1.950', '1.343', '2.040'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M2", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M2 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M2', marker_color='rgb(60,180,75)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['12.552', '28.142', '34.866', '33.760', '30.362', '27.477', '22.317', '16.624', '10.221', '6.285', '3.853', '2.342', '3.101'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M3", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M3 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M3', marker_color='rgb(0,130,200)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['1.572', '7.198', '17.117', '24.482', '27.654', '28.867', '27.013', '22.357', '16.369', '13.342', '9.081', '6.584', '7.308'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M4", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M4 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M4', marker_color='rgb(245,130,48)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.177', '1.028', '3.369', '7.020', '10.741', '13.425', '16.108', '16.946', '13.654', '11.075', '7.060', '3.919', '3.424'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M5", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M5 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M5', marker_color='rgb(145,30,180)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.014', '0.147', '0.539', '0.898', '1.445', '2.123', '3.598', '7.842', '8.837', '7.916', '6.015', '4.466', '4.884'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M6", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M6 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M6', marker_color='rgb(70,240,240)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.003', '0.012', '0.120', '0.309', '0.460', '0.801', '2.013', '7.288', '10.854', '10.506', '6.766', '3.984', '2.921'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M7", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M7 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M7', marker_color='rgb(0,0,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.001', '0.018', '0.075', '0.142', '0.279', '0.579', '4.052', '9.357', '10.690', '11.111', '9.456', '8.756'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M8", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M8 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M8', marker_color='rgb(210,245,80)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.003', '0.010', '0.019', '0.043', '0.086', '0.103', '0.300', '2.427', '7.132', '9.093', '8.937', '7.208', '4.578'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M9", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M9 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M9', marker_color='rgb(0,128,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.000', '0.002', '0.017', '0.033', '0.051', '0.149', '1.564', '5.752', '9.613', '12.453', '15.218', '13.762'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M10", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M10 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M10', marker_color='rgb(220,190,255)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.003', '0.004', '0.028', '0.019', '0.022', '0.068', '0.558', '3.286', '5.387', '9.235', '9.583', '6.008'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M11", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M11 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M11', marker_color='rgb(170,255,195)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.002', '0.001', '0.001', '0.036', '0.732', '4.020', '8.839', '15.911', '25.388', '20.153'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M12", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M12 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M12', marker_color='rgb(255,215,180)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.003', '0.003', '0.005', '0.014', '0.119', '0.810', '1.324', '3.969', '5.143', '7.068'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M13", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M13 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M13', marker_color='rgb(0,0,0)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~11', '11~26', '26~41', '41~55', '55~94', '94~158', '158~1644'], y=['0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.004', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.050', '0.517', '0.967', '2.888', '4.948', '15.559'], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M14", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M14 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M14', marker_color='rgb(128,0,0)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.update_layout(title_text='<b>Metal Layer Usage by Length: euunit n3</b>', title_font_size=28, yaxis=dict(title='<b>Metal Layer Usage (%)</b>', titlefont_size=20, showticklabels=False), xaxis=dict(title='<b>Net Length Range (um)</b>', titlefont_size=20, tickfont_size=16))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(font=dict(size=14),borderwidth=1))
fig.show()
```

...however, the outcome looks like this:-

[image: not 100 percent stacked bar]

...I am not quite sure why the bars do not fully occupy the vertical height of the plot area. Does the sum total of numbers in each bin (e.g. 0~1, 1~2, etc.) have to add up to exactly 100? I am asking because due to rounding some add up to 100.001 and others 99.999, etc. Or am I supposed to declare some kind of special format (e.g. %) for the numbers in each column?

The plotly options are all relatively new to me, so I could very well be missing something simple. Does anyone have any suggestions? Note that barmode='relative' did not change the outcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The data for the y-axis is a string, so change it to a number, and then change mode to relative.

Comment: @r-beginners yup, that was indeed the problem. I removed the ' characters around the y values and now it looks as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the ' characters around the y values and adding 'relative' for barmode produced the correct outcome...

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
binnum_attr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
tnl_attr=[164549.654, 278570.473, 201857.2155, 146326.9935, 116167.091, 98121.201, 86260.078, 79611.275, 346547.786, 573329.789, 345360.231, 513364.5035, 287341.8995, 472867.1225, 143591.5138]
pop_attr=[296699, 195322, 82853, 42382, 26001, 17926, 13310, 10637, 33974, 32444, 12302, 12449, 4635, 4781, 785]
verbose_customdata = np.stack((binnum_attr, tnl_attr, pop_attr), axis=-1)

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[3.618, 1.526, 0.899, 0.674, 0.587, 0.566, 0.566, 0.622, 0.644, 0.392, 0.185, 0.094, 0.056, 0.029, 0.060], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M0", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M0 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M0', marker_color='rgb(128,128,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[36.797, 21.312, 12.348, 9.136, 8.275, 8.028, 8.307, 8.749, 9.195, 5.667, 3.191, 1.561, 0.890, 0.466, 0.377], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M1", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M1 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M1', marker_color='rgb(230,25,75)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[45.265, 40.620, 30.699, 23.548, 20.190, 18.252, 17.691, 18.222, 17.714, 12.791, 7.958, 4.590, 2.436, 1.391, 2.040], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M2", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M2 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M2', marker_color='rgb(60,180,75)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[12.552, 28.142, 34.866, 33.760, 30.362, 27.477, 24.941, 23.311, 20.421, 16.449, 11.854, 7.587, 4.617, 2.679, 3.101], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M3", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M3 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M3', marker_color='rgb(0,130,200)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[1.572, 7.198, 17.117, 24.482, 27.654, 28.867, 28.483, 27.705, 25.384, 22.417, 17.922, 14.306, 10.080, 7.284, 7.308], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M4", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M4 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M4', marker_color='rgb(245,130,48)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.177, 1.028, 3.369, 7.020, 10.741, 13.425, 15.438, 16.022, 16.681, 17.102, 14.868, 11.920, 8.350, 4.642, 3.424], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M5", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M5 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M5', marker_color='rgb(145,30,180)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.014, 0.147, 0.539, 0.898, 1.445, 2.123, 2.673, 2.974, 4.886, 7.980, 9.202, 8.248, 6.609, 4.891, 4.884], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M6", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M6 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M6', marker_color='rgb(70,240,240)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.003, 0.012, 0.120, 0.309, 0.460, 0.801, 1.243, 1.570, 3.151, 7.628, 10.602, 10.732, 7.845, 4.673, 2.921], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M7", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M7 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M7', marker_color='rgb(0,0,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.001, 0.018, 0.075, 0.142, 0.279, 0.341, 0.416, 1.054, 4.200, 7.894, 10.699, 11.194, 9.985, 8.756], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M8", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M8 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M8', marker_color='rgb(210,245,80)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.003, 0.010, 0.019, 0.043, 0.086, 0.103, 0.191, 0.265, 0.409, 2.451, 5.941, 8.565, 9.452, 7.728, 4.578], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M9", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M9 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M9', marker_color='rgb(0,128,128)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.000, 0.002, 0.017, 0.033, 0.051, 0.050, 0.085, 0.274, 1.564, 4.395, 8.221, 11.563, 14.457, 13.762], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M10", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M10 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M10', marker_color='rgb(220,190,255)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.003, 0.004, 0.028, 0.019, 0.022, 0.049, 0.030, 0.095, 0.514, 2.237, 4.737, 8.285, 9.802, 6.008], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M11", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M11 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M11', marker_color='rgb(170,255,195)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.025, 0.083, 0.695, 2.848, 6.794, 13.261, 22.648, 20.153], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M12", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M12 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M12', marker_color='rgb(255,215,180)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.003, 0.003, 0.005, 0.024, 0.004, 0.008, 0.093, 0.582, 1.165, 3.187, 4.934, 7.068], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M13", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M13 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M13', marker_color='rgb(0,0,0)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=['0~1', '1~2', '2~3', '3~4', '4~5', '5~6', '6~7', '7~8', '8~13', '13~24', '24~33', '33~53', '53~73', '73~158', '158~1644'], y=[0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.004, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.056, 0.321, 0.781, 2.176, 4.394, 15.559], customdata=verbose_customdata, legendgroup="M14", hovertemplate='<b>Bin: %{customdata[0]: .0f}</b><br>'+'<b>M14 portion: %{y:.2f}%</b><br>'+'<b>Total length (all layers): %{customdata[1]:.2f}</b><br>'+'<b>Nets: %{customdata[2]: .0f}</b><br>', name='M14', marker_color='rgb(128,0,0)', marker_opacity=1.0))
fig.update_layout(barmode='relative')
fig.update_layout(title_text='<b>Metal Layer Usage by Length: block node</b>', title_font_size=28, yaxis=dict(title='<b>Metal Layer Usage (%)</b>', titlefont_size=20, tickfont_size=16), xaxis=dict(title='<b>Net Length Range (um)</b>', titlefont_size=20, tickfont_size=16))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(font=dict(size=14),borderwidth=1))
fig.show()
```

...results in...

[image: correct 100% stacked bar chart]